# CodeIgniter join two tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, join

I am trying to join two tables together using CodeIgniter.  I used CodeIgniter user guide for help. I am having some issues where only one table's data is displayed and I don't know why. Can someone help me out?

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
function getall(){      
    $this->load->model('result_model');
    $data['query'] =
    $this->result_model->result_getall();
    $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
 function result_getall(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tblanswers');
    $this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'left'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

    }
```

**View**

```
    <div>    


 <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>      
                     //tblanswers
                   <?php echo $row->answerA;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->answerB;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->answerC;?><br>
                   <?php echo $row->comment;?><br>
                  //credentials
                    <?php echo $row->name; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>  


   </div>
```

Comment: use echo $this->db->last_query() to see the generated query.

Comment: this is the query that is generated SELECT * FROM (`tblanswers`) LEFT JOIN `credentials` ON `tblanswers`.`answerid` = `credentials`.`cid`

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter join 2 table data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200548/codeigniter-join-2-table-data)

Comment: use var_dump($query->result())..is it showing second table data? what is the output of this?

Comment: can u explain more on the dublicate table ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do a left join?

Comment: where shuld i add the var_dump ?

Comment: @Mischa no i am not sure is there a better way instead of left join ?

Comment: there might be columns with same name so it may be overriding try selecting and aliasing each column you need

Comment: Well, it depends what you want. But if you remove the `'left'` parameter from your `join` call you will get records from `tblanswers` that have related records in `credentials`. If you use a left join, you get all the records from `tblanswers` and there may not be any related records in `credentials`, so those fields stay empty.

Comment: there are no columns with the same name i made sure of that

Comment: when i remove left join all the records disapiere

Comment: So it's a problem with your data, not with your code. There are not records with `tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid`.

Comment: what can be wrong with the data ?

Comment: There are not records with `tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid`.

Comment: im sorry i dount undarstand can u expand more on your comment ?

Comment: There are no records in `tblanswers` that have an `answerid` that is equal to the `cid` column of any records in the `credentials` table. From this question it seems you have no idea how joins work. Please have a look at [this](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in controller and see whats the result.Also,show us if you are getting any error and make sure there is data in your table :).

**Controller**

```
function getall(){      
    $this->load->model('result_model');
    $data['query'] =$this->result_model->result_getall();
    print_r($data['query']);
    die();
    $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
    }
```

Comment: i tried the code this is what i got : rray ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [answerid] => 180 [userid] => [questionid] => 0 [answerA] => DASDAS [answerB] => DSAD [answerC] => ASD [comment] => testas [cid] => [name] => [second_name] => [phone] => [email] => ) )

Answer (score 2):

```
function result_getall(){

$this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*');
$this->db->from('tblanswers');
$this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'left'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: that did not do anything but tnx for ur help