# codeigniter join database tables

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have 2 database tables, one is for posts and the other for categories, and each post is assigned to a category by the category ID.

I want to show the category name on the posts page and on each post I want to show the category assigned to it, so I did a join database tables, the category name is showing normally on the main posts page, but when I click on a post the category is now showing, and I get an `Undefined index: name`

Model code:

```
<?php
  class Yacht_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
      $this->load->database();
    }
    public function get_yachts($slug = FALSE){
      if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id = yachts.category');
        $query = $this->db->get('yachts');
        return $query->result_array();
      }
      $query = $this->db->get_where('yachts', array('slug' => $slug));
      return $query->row_array();
    }
    public function get_yachts_by_category($cat_id){
      $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id = yachts.category');
      $query = $this->db->get_where('yachts', array('category' => $cat_id));
      return $query->result_array();
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Controller code:

```
<?php
  class Yachts extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
      $data['title'] = 'Yachts';
      $data['yachts'] = $this->yacht_model->get_yachts();

      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('yachts/index', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function view($slug = NULL){
      $data['yacht'] = $this->yacht_model->get_yachts($slug);
      if(empty($data['yacht'])){
        show_404();
      }
      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('yachts/view', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
  }
 ?>
```

HTML code for post:

```
<section>
    <div class="rows inner_banner inner_banner_2">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><span><?php echo $yacht['name']; ?></span></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#inner-page-title">Anasayfa</a>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> </li>
                <li><a href="#inner-page-title" class="bread-acti">Gulet Kiralama</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

the `$yacht['name'];` is from the categories table, it should show the category name.

I am not sure if I was clear enough explaining my issue, if not please tell me and I can provide you any information or detail you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter join 2 table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200548/codeigniter-join-2-table-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to, I was making the join tables inside the if statement which set to FALSE at default, that's why inside the post page the join is not working, but when I place it outside the if statement, it works fine

Before:

```
public function get_yachts($slug = FALSE){
      if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id = yachts.category');
        $query = $this->db->get('yachts');
        return $query->result_array();
      }
      $query = $this->db->get_where('yachts', array('slug' => $slug));
      return $query->row_array();
    }
```

After:

```
public function get_yachts($slug = FALSE){
      if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $this->db->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id = yachts.category');
        $query = $this->db->get('yachts');
        return $query->result_array();
      }
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id = yachts.category');
      $query = $this->db->get_where('yachts', array('slug' => $slug));
      return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to fetch that category name from database using post_id.

Or

2) you can store that categories and post names mapping array in a session and you can show the category name for the relavent post from session data.

Answer (score 0):

if you have post and category table you can access it either by using joining or making a function which returns the category name by passing category id
let me show you both

1st By using Joining
In your Post modal create this function

```
   function getPosts(){
                   $this->db->select('post.*,post_category.*')
                        ->from('post')
                        ->join('post_category','post_category.id=post.post_category','left');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result_array();
     }
```

2nd Method in your category Model write function

```
public function getCategoryById($id = Null){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('post_category',array('id'=>$id));;
        return $query->row()->category_title;
    }
```

If you are using the first method then code in your view file will something like

```
<?php if(isset($posts) && count($posts) > 0){ 
        foreach($posts as $k => $val){
  ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $k++?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['post_title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['post_content']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['category_title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['slug']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

if you want to use the 2nd method the code in your view will be something like

```
 <?php if(isset($posts) && count($posts) > 0){ 
        foreach($posts as $k => $val){
  ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $k++?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['post_title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['post_content']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->category_model->getCategoryById($val['post_category'])?></td>
    <td><?php echo $val['slug']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } } ?>
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

> You may Try this simple Query. i Hope this will work as you want.

```
$getData=$this->db->query("SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id and table1.id='1'");
$result=$getData->result_array();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```